# Latex verbatim:how to show the file directoy created by tree command?

Tags: latex, verbatim

I want to insert a file directory diagram created by tree command using verbatim enviroment. But in the output document, only file names are kept, and the connection lines are disapeared.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
 .
 ├── app
 ├── bakery
 ├── build
 ├── CHANGELOG.md
 ├── composer.json
 ├── composer.lock
 ├── docker
 ├── sponsors
 ├── STYLE-GUIDE.md
 └── webserver-configs

 \end{Verbatim}

 \end{document}
```

I have tried using fancyvrb package by setting showtabs true, but the connection lines are still not printed in the document.

Is there any way?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Does the font you use contain the symbols necessary to draw your diagram?

Comment: I have added a minimal working example, please have a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that these unicode characters are not included in the default mono font. If you use an unicode-capable engine, such as xelatex, and a font which contains them, e.g. DejaVu Sans Mono, the will be visible in the document:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
 .
 ├── app
 ├── bakery
 ├── build
 ├── CHANGELOG.md
 ├── composer.json
 ├── composer.lock
 ├── docker
 ├── sponsors
 ├── STYLE-GUIDE.md
 └── webserver-configs

 \end{Verbatim}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you prefer `pdflatex`, the `pmboxdraw` package can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
 .
 ├── app
 ├── bakery
 ├── build
 ├── CHANGELOG.md
 ├── composer.json
 ├── composer.lock
 ├── docker
 ├── sponsors
 ├── STYLE-GUIDE.md
 └── webserver-configs

 \end{Verbatim}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I use xelatex, but the default font is Times New Rome. I'll try to use the DejaVu Sans Mono. Thank you again!

Comment: @samcarter If I still want to use the default mono font, and for those unicode characters not supported,  I want to draw them use a different font? i.e., I want use a substitute font only for those unsupported characters. Thanks!

Comment: @bruin Isn't this what the second approach does? Anyway if you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: @samcarter I asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816096/latex-verbatim-show-characters-using-a-fallback-font). Thanks!