# Latex verbatim: show characters using a fallback font?

Tags: fonts, latex, verbatim

I use a specific monofont for verbatim blocks. In one of my verbatim block, some characters are not included in the font. As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036409/latex-verbatimhow-to-show-the-file-directoy-created-by-tree-command), one can use either a different font, or use `pmboxdraw` package to render the un-supported characters. But it seems that it does not work for me.

The following is a MWE, in which the black circle (i.e., 1st character of the second line) can not be drawn correctly. My intention is that to use the monofont I used for the verbatim block, and use whatever substitute font for the black circle character. Is there a solution for that? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Path=./fonts/PragmataPro/,
    UprightFont=*-R,
    ItalicFont=*-RI,
    BoldFont=*-B,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BI]{PragmataPro}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
$ systemctl status redsocks
● redsocks.service - Redsocks transparent SOCKS proxy redirector
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redsocks.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-10-28 16:14:16 CST; 5s ago
  Process: 1499 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/redsocks -c ${CONFFILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1496 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/redsocks -t -c ${CONFFILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The output using `xelatex` shows that the black circle is rendered incorrectly:

[image]

Btw, if I don't specify the customized monofont, the black circle will not be drawn at all.

Comment: The `pmboxdraw` package is not to render un-supported characters in general, it is specific to render box drawings characters. I don't think linking back to a question about box drawing characters is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace individual symbols with the `newunicodechar` package. You just need to find a font that contains the character, see e.g. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/fontsupport.htm

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Monaco}

\newfontfamily{\dejamono}{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\newunicodechar{●}{{\dejamono ●}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
$ systemctl status redsocks
● redsocks.service - Redsocks transparent SOCKS proxy redirector
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redsocks.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-10-28 16:14:16 CST; 5s ago
  Process: 1499 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/redsocks -c ${CONFFILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1496 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/redsocks -t -c ${CONFFILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

(I'm using `Monaco` font for the example above, because this font also lacks the symbol and I don't have the proprietary `PragmataPro` font)

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: This replaces the `●` with dejamono in _all_ text. What if I only want to use dejamono for `●` in monospace text, and use the regular font in normal text?

Comment: @Eric If you have a new question, please use the "ask question" to ask a new question

Comment: I'd argue this is same question - your solution has effects that weren't asked for in text outside the `Verbatim` block.

Comment: @Eric Feel free to not ask a new question, but not many people will see your comment here, so chances that you get an answer are not very big ...